# PHP Garbage collection and memory optimizations

Tags: php, memory, memory-management, benchmarking

I'm doing some PHP memory benchmarks and i'm wondering if there is a way to optimize the garbage collector in order to reduce the memory consumption (as it is possible in other languages such as JAVA).

I've found only three customizable parameters related to GC in the php.ini: `session.gc_probability`, `session.gc_divisor` and `session.gc_maxlifetime`. This is only for sessions and i'm not benchmarking that.

Possible optimizations i know so far are code related, such as avoiding circular references and by forcing a garbage collecting cycle by calling `gc_collect_cycles()` (thanks to this article http://www.alexatnet.com/comment/86).

Someone know any configuration tricks or good practices in PHP memory management ?

Comment: There's nothing much you can do via configuration directives, only by writing code in such a way where you reduce memory usage - which in itself is a mistery for majority of "programmers" out there :)

Comment: Unless you're actually hitting memory consumption and/or performance problems due to GC issues, I really wouldn't worry about it as it will for the most part be a [tag:micro-optimization]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So far as I know, forcing a collection with `gc_collect_cycles()` is the closest you can get to minimising memory usage at time t.

GC is of course a time-bound operation, and an application is rarely critically memory-bound, and as such it does not really make sense to offer options to unnecessarily trigger GC runs throughout the program's execution. Along this vein, PHP *does* offer the ability to turn the cycle collector on and off on demand (`gc_enable()`, `gc_disable()`) such that you can optimise your code for time (avoiding the overhead of the GC deciding to kick off) - of course it's easy to see how this might be useful.

In general, PHP by philosophy avoids topics such as memory management and GC, and your benchmarks should perhaps pay respect to this for a more real-world outlook.

Hope this helps.

(A nod to @GordonM's comment citing micro-optimisation, also.)

Comment: The fact is that i was searching those kind of gc micro-optimisation. But, obvioulsy PHP garbage collector cannot be tuned. I wanted to be sure. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

In general PHPs memory management works out of the box for all variables that you declare and use. Using the concept refcounting, PHP sees if a variable is not used anymore and then automatically cleans it up.

The garbage collector is only interesting for the cases where objects have cyclic references, A points to B, B points back to A. In this case refcounting doesn't work.

If there are exactly 10.000 objects in PHP memory that are potentically cyclic, potentially not used anymore, then the PHP garbage collector triggers if it enabled, which it is by default. You can disable or enable it with `gc_enable()` and `gc_disable()` at runtime.

You can also call `gc_collect_cycles()` to cleanup these objects manually.

But how to optimize this process, if you need to? Running the cycle collector doesn't have to be efficient or useful, from the 10.000 potential objects, many of them could still be in use and cannot be cleaned up. In this case you are wasting CPU cycles to check all objects and deciding not to clean them up. There will be no memory reduction if you do this.

Usually the GC only triggers in long running scripts, and only sometimes in short web-requests when they create too many objects. In general you shouldn't think about this too much, because the defaults work for 99% of the use-cases.

With the "garbage_stats" PHP extension you can access metrics and stats about how efficient and fast the GC ran and how much memory was reduced. It works on PHP 7+ (because hooks are only available since then): https://github.com/tideways/php_garbage_stats

If you have installed the extension, you can see garbage collection stats for CLI scripts by calling them:

```
$ php -dgc_stats.enable=1 -dgc_stats.show_report=1 test.php

Found 7 garbage collection runs in current script.

Collected | Efficency% | Duration | Memory Before | Memory After | Reduction% | Function
----------|------------|----------|---------------|--------------|------------|---------
        0 |     0.00 % |  0.01 ms |        365824 |       366320 |    -0.14 % | gc_collect_cycles
    10000 |   100.00 % |  2.75 ms |       4651320 |       491816 |    89.43 % | foo
    10000 |   100.00 % |  3.54 ms |       4652784 |       493280 |    89.40 % | foo
    10000 |   100.00 % |  2.11 ms |       4654248 |       494744 |    89.37 % | foo
    10000 |   100.00 % |  3.26 ms |       4656168 |       496664 |    89.33 % | Test::foo
     9000 |    90.00 % |  1.51 ms |       4694680 |       951176 |    79.74 % | Test::foo
    10000 |   100.00 % |  3.11 ms |       5112272 |       952768 |    81.36 % | Test::foo
```

From a web (Apache or FPM for example) request, you can use the function `$runs = gc_stats();` to access this information and write it to a log file.

based on this information you can make the only decision possible to optimize: To enable or disable the GC in your script depending on how efficient it runs.

Answer (score 0):

I use unset() method to clear a variable when I don't need it anymore.